# Pinning ipython3 qtconlsole to launcher

Tags: 12.04, unity, python, unity-dash

I've installed both `ipython` (which uses Python 2.7) and `ipython3`, and the respective `qtconsole` packages. Both work when I call them from the terminal like `ipython qtconsole`. However, when I search for them in the dash home, only the 2.7 versions (of both the shell and qtconsole) appear, as executables. Searching for `ipython3` only yields the `ipython3` file from `/usr/bin`. Changing to the "application lens" doesn't affect the results.

Also, even if I can start both from the terminal, I can only pin the running 2.7 version to the launcher -- or, to be more exact, I can *pin* the v3 console, but the icon looks somehow blurred, and it doesn't start anything when I click it.

So, whats happening here? Is the v3 package hidden somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's a problem with the `.desktop` file.  These either don't exist or don't refer correctly to ipython3.   Also see the comments at the bottom, if you want to see how it's expected to work.

```
$ locate ipy | grep desk
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/ipython-qtconsole:ipython-qtconsole.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/ipython:ipython.desktop

$ more /usr/share/app-install/desktop/ipython-qtconsole:ipython-qtconsole.desktop
# If you want ipython to appear in a linux app launcher ("start menu"), install
# this by doing:
# sudo desktop-file-install ipython-qtconsole.desktop
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved the issue by just copying the existing desktop file and edit it a bit to use `ipython3`.

Comment: Could you please specify exactly what you did to get this working?